# Nodejs class return undefined

Tags: node.js, database

I have a nodejs code like this

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

class ConnectDatabase{
    constructor(){
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'mydatabase'
        });
    };

    getVersion() {
        this.connection.query('SELECT * FROM version', function (err, results) {
            return results[0].version // if use console.log() i get my data
        });
    };
};

var APP = new ConnectDatabase()
console.log(APP.getVersion());
```

when i use console.log(results[0].version), i get my data, but when i use return my data becomes undefined

Comment: Maybe you can define a variable inside `getVersion`, say `var ret;` and assign the value of `results[0].version` to it, like `ret = results[0].version;`

Comment: Your `.getVersion` is asynchron, you handle it like its synchron. Use callback or promise, Short & quick explanation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20635030/5781499

Answer (score 0):

I am Node js Developer i am using mongodb. i think everything fine.
3 possible problem

1 first check xampp is running
2 connection build with database or not
3 table name

Comment: The question is about MySQL not MongoDB.

Comment: I know but first check your connection is build or not. your connection with database.
and console only result not result[0].

Comment: Of course connection is built, OP says the results are logged to console. And why there is XAMPP when Node.js is used for server?

Comment: because your are using mysql as the database.

Comment: Although XAMPP does come with MySQL, in this case, there seems to be no dependency on XAMPP because MySQL can be installed on your system without XAMPP.

Comment: which operating system your are using

Comment: He is mixing synchron & asyncrhon code execeution. The problems your are list have absolut nothing todo with his problem. As node developer you should now what sync/async code execution is, and how to handle it.